# Microsoft's DirectX 11 Tutorials Crash When Releasing Variables

Tags: c++, directx-11

Last year I learnt DirectX 9 at university and this year we've been using DirectX 11. We've been given a framework which does A LOT of stuff in the 'background' (e.g. initialising the window, creating the buffers, loading the shaders etc.) so that we could focus on learning how to do particle effects etc.

I've decided that I want to learn how to create a DirectX 11 framework for myself but none of the tutorials I've found work properly. Then, when I tried the DirectX 11 tutorials provided with the S.D.K. (i.e. from Microsoft) I found that all of them crash when releasing the variables (upon closing the window).

I've tried messing around with it and re-ordering them, but it always crashes on the last variable that it needs to release. The strange thing is that if I comment out any one of the releases then it doesn't crash.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who's as stupid as myself, I give you three words.

UPDATE GRAPHICS DRIVERS!

... I'm going to go and sit in the corner for a while now...